# How to create a df by extracting a column from each df of a list of dfs in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, large-data

I've many list of dataframes like `split_plot_data2`, and I want to make a separate single dataframe in which columns 3 and 2 will be there. Column 3 is common for all and col 2 will be separately added with the name of col 1.

```
head(split_plot_data2)
$EE87786ln1
# A tibble: 1,584 × 4
   EE_variant    lambda variable                     value
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 blood_vessel_h16                 0
 2 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 adrenal_gland_h16                0
 3 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 bone_element_h16                 0
 4 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 Bronchus_h16                     0
 5 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 esophagus_h16                    0
 6 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 extraembryonic_structure_h16     0
 7 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 eye_h16                          0
 8 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 gonad_h16                        0
 9 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 heart_h16                        0
10 EE87786ln1 0.0000228 kidney_h16                       0
# ℹ 1,574 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

$EE87787ln1
# A tibble: 1,560 × 4
   EE_variant    lambda variable                     value
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 blood_vessel_h16                 0
 2 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 adrenal_gland_h16                0
 3 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 bone_element_h16                 0
 4 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 Bronchus_h16                     0
 5 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 esophagus_h16                    0
 6 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 extraembryonic_structure_h16     0
 7 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 eye_h16                          0
 8 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 gonad_h16                        0
 9 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 heart_h16                        0
10 EE87787ln1 0.0000751 kidney_h16                       0
# ℹ 1,550 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

$EE87788ln1
# A tibble: 1,608 × 4
   EE_variant    lambda variable                     value
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 blood_vessel_h16                 0
 2 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 adrenal_gland_h16                0
 3 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 bone_element_h16                 0
 4 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 Bronchus_h16                     0
 5 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 esophagus_h16                    0
 6 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 extraembryonic_structure_h16     0
 7 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 eye_h16                          0
 8 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 gonad_h16                        0
 9 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 heart_h16                        0
10 EE87788ln1 0.0000761 kidney_h16                       0
# ℹ 1,598 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

$EE87789ln1
# A tibble: 1,608 × 4
   EE_variant    lambda variable                     value
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 blood_vessel_h16                 0
 2 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 adrenal_gland_h16                0
 3 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 bone_element_h16                 0
 4 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 Bronchus_h16                     0
 5 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 esophagus_h16                    0
 6 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 extraembryonic_structure_h16     0
 7 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 eye_h16                          0
 8 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 gonad_h16                        0
 9 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 heart_h16                        0
10 EE87789ln1 0.0000732 kidney_h16                       0
# ℹ 1,598 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

$EE87790ln1
# A tibble: 1,536 × 4
   EE_variant    lambda variable                     value
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 blood_vessel_h16                 0
 2 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 adrenal_gland_h16                0
 3 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 bone_element_h16                 0
 4 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 Bronchus_h16                     0
 5 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 esophagus_h16                    0
 6 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 extraembryonic_structure_h16     0
 7 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 eye_h16                          0
 8 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 gonad_h16                        0
 9 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 heart_h16                        0
10 EE87790ln1 0.0000328 kidney_h16                       0
# ℹ 1,526 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

$EE87791ln1
# A tibble: 1,536 × 4
   EE_variant    lambda variable                     value
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl>
 1 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 blood_vessel_h16                 0
 2 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 adrenal_gland_h16                0
 3 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 bone_element_h16                 0
 4 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 Bronchus_h16                     0
 5 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 esophagus_h16                    0
 6 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 extraembryonic_structure_h16     0
 7 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 eye_h16                          0
 8 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 gonad_h16                        0
 9 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 heart_h16                        0
10 EE87791ln1 0.0000444 kidney_h16                       0
# ℹ 1,526 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The expected dataframe would look like this,

```
head(comb_plot_lamb)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  Variable               Lambda_EE87802 Lambda_EE87786 Lambda_EE87787 Lambda_EE87788 Lambda_EE87789 Lambda_EE87790 Lambda_EE87791
  <chr>                       <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 blood_vessel_h16        0.0000348      0.0000228      0.0000751      0.0000761      0.0000732      0.0000328      0.0000444
2 adrenal_gland_h16       0.0000348      0.0000228      0.0000751      0.0000761      0.0000732      0.0000328      0.0000444
3 bone_element_h16        0.0000348      0.0000228      0.0000751      0.0000761      0.0000732      0.0000328      0.0000444
4 Bronchus_h16            0.0000348      0.0000228      0.0000751      0.0000761      0.0000732      0.0000328      0.0000444
5 esophagus_h16           0.0000348      0.0000228      0.0000751      0.0000761      0.0000732      0.0000328      0.0000444
6 extraembryonic_struct…  0.0000348      0.0000228      0.0000751      0.0000761      0.0000732      0.0000328      0.0000444
```

What I did, but I wonder how can I make this thing at a go rather than writing multiple lines to get every column of lambda values.

```
n1 <- sapply(split_plot_data2, nrow)
n2 <- max(n1)
n4 <- which.max(n1)
comb_plot_data <- split_plot_data2[[n4]][1:4]
comb_plot_data2 <- comb_plot_data[, c(3,2)]

colnames(comb_plot_data2) <- c('Variable','Lambda_EE87802)

comb_plot_lamb <- comb_plot_data2

comb_plot_lamb$Lambda_EE87786 <- c(split_plot_data2[[1]]$lambda, rep(NA, nrow(comb_plot_lamb)-length(split_plot_data2[[1]]$lambda)))
comb_plot_lamb$Lambda_EE87787 <- c(split_plot_data2[[2]]$lambda, rep(NA, nrow(comb_plot_lamb)-length(split_plot_data2[[2]]$lambda)))
comb_plot_lamb$Lambda_EE87788 <- c(split_plot_data2[[3]]$lambda, rep(NA, nrow(comb_plot_lamb)-length(split_plot_data2[[3]]$lambda)))
comb_plot_lamb$Lambda_EE87789 <- c(split_plot_data2[[4]]$lambda, rep(NA, nrow(comb_plot_lamb)-length(split_plot_data2[[4]]$lambda)))
comb_plot_lamb$Lambda_EE87790 <- c(split_plot_data2[[5]]$lambda, rep(NA, nrow(comb_plot_lamb)-length(split_plot_data2[[5]]$lambda)))
comb_plot_lamb$Lambda_EE87791 <- c(split_plot_data2[[6]]$lambda, rep(NA, nrow(comb_plot_lamb)-length(split_plot_data2[[6]]$lambda)))
```

Comment: (Advice extracted & slightly paraphrase from the below answer). Please assist helpers by providing your data in a more accessible format. (`dput()` is ideal.) It took longer to create the test data than it did to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(purrr)
})

df1 %>%
  group_split(EE_variant) %>%
  map(\(x) {
    newname <- first(x$EE_variant) %>% as.character()
    newname <- paste0("Lambda_", newname)
    x %>%
      select(-EE_variant) %>%
      rename(!!sym(newname) := lambda) %>% 
      select(2, 1)
  }) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = "variable")
#> # A tibble: 50 × 4
#>    variable Lambda_EE87786 Lambda_EE87787 Lambda_EE87802
#>    <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1 var 1               1.4            2.5            0.2
#>  2 var 2               1.5            1.9            0.2
#>  3 var 3               1.5            2.1            0.2
#>  4 var 4               1.3            1.8            0.2
#>  5 var 5               1.5            2.2            0.2
#>  6 var 6               1.3            2.1            0.4
#>  7 var 7               1.6            1.7            0.3
#>  8 var 8               1              1.8            0.2
#>  9 var 9               1.3            1.8            0.2
#> 10 var 10              1.4            2.5            0.1
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Inspired in [Limey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033107/8245406), here is a solution that binds the rows and then reshapes the data to wide format.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(purrr)
})

df1 %>%
  group_by(variable, EE_variant) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_split(EE_variant) %>%
  map(select, -value) %>%
  bind_rows() %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, variable),
    names_from = EE_variant,
    names_glue = "Lambda_{EE_variant}",
    values_from = lambda
  ) %>%
  select(-id) %>% 
  arrange(variable)
#> # A tibble: 50 × 4
#>    variable Lambda_EE87786 Lambda_EE87787 Lambda_EE87802
#>    <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1 var 01              1.6            1.7            0.3
#>  2 var 01              1              1.8            0.2
#>  3 var 01              1.3            1.8            0.2
#>  4 var 01              1.4            2.5            0.1
#>  5 var 01              1.7            1.8            0.2
#>  6 var 01              1              1.6            0.2
#>  7 var 01              1.4            2.3            0.3
#>  8 var 01              1.3            2.5            0.4
#>  9 var 01              1.1            2.3            0.2
#> 10 var 02              1.3            2.1            0.4
#> # ℹ 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test data

```r
# use a built.in data set to make the example reproducible
set.seed(2023)
df1 <- iris[c(5:3)]
df1$variable <- sprintf("var %02d", sample(10, 50, TRUE))
df1 <- df1[c(1, 2, 4, 3)]
names(df1) <- c("EE_variant", "lambda", "variable", "value")
df1$EE_variant <- as.character(df1$EE_variant)
df1$EE_variant <- rep(c("EE87802", "EE87786", "EE87787"), each = 50)
head(df1)
#>   EE_variant lambda variable value
#> 1    EE87802    0.2   var 05   1.4
#> 2    EE87802    0.2   var 09   1.4
#> 3    EE87802    0.2   var 08   1.3
#> 4    EE87802    0.2   var 03   1.5
#> 5    EE87802    0.2   var 10   1.4
#> 6    EE87802    0.4   var 02   1.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Apologies, Rui.  Your question showed as deleted when I first loaded the page.  I did not intend to copy.  Though similar, I think our answers are sufficiently different to be worth keeping both.

Comment: @Limey Yes, the answers are different enough. I had thought of `pivot_wider` then opted for a join. I think that to pivot should be more computationally efficient, I'll try and come back to this.

Comment: Thanks @Rui, 
However, with my dataset it produces error,
`Error in `vctrs::vec_locate_matches()`:
! Match procedure results in an allocation larger than 2^31-1 elements. Attempted allocation size was 29579996160.`
I want to mention that the length of all my df is not similar.

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj See if the edit solves it.

Comment: @Limey Apparently I was partly wrong, for small data sets it's faster to join. When the table grows, your solution is faster.

Comment: Now the result is similar to Limey
`head(T2)
# A tibble: 6 × 26
  variable            Lambda_EE87786ln1 Lambda_EE87787ln1 Lambda_EE87788ln1 Lambda_EE87789ln1 Lambda_EE87790ln1 Lambda_EE87791ln1
  <chr>               <list>            <list>            <list>            <list>            <list>            <list>           
1 blood_vessel_h16    <dbl [66]>        <dbl [65]>        <dbl [67]>        <dbl [67]>        <dbl [64]>        <dbl [64]>       
2 adrenal_gland_h16   <dbl [66]>        <dbl [65]>        <dbl [67]>        <dbl [67]>        <dbl [64]>        <dbl [64]>  `

Comment: What I'm getting,
`tibble [24 × 26] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)`

My expectation:

`tibble [1,632 × 26] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)`

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj That output shows list columns, do you have repeated values in column `lambda` for the same `EE_variant`?

Comment: The `variables` are repeated, the number of variables is 24, and this repetition is not similar for all the dfs. Some have 66 times some might have 68 times repetition, but it is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255159/discussion-between-rui-barradas-and-debajyoti-kabiraj).

Comment: Thank you so much @Rui Barradas, I think this is working well now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfList %>% 
  # Create a single, grouped data frame
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(EE_variant) %>%
  # Extract the information from each group in turn...
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      varName <- paste0("Lambda_", stringr::str_sub(.y$EE_variant, 1, 7))
      tibble(
        Variable = .x$variable,
        Name = varName,
        Lambda = .x$lambda
      )
    }
  ) %>% 
  # ... and bind the results together
  bind_rows() %>% 
  # Pivot to the required format
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Name,
    values_from = Lambda
  )
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   Variable                     Lambda_EE87786 Lambda_EE87787
   <chr>                                 <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 blood_vessel_h16                  0.0000228      0.0000751
 2 adrenal_gland_h16                 0.0000228      0.0000751
 3 bone_element_h16                  0.0000228      0.0000751
 4 Bronchus_h16                      0.0000228      0.0000751
 5 esophagus_h16                     0.0000228      0.0000751
 6 extraembryonic_structure_h16      0.0000228      0.0000751
 7 eye_h16                           0.0000228      0.0000751
 8 gonad_h16                         0.0000228      0.0000751
 9 heart_h16                         0.0000228      0.0000751
10 kidney_h16                        0.0000228      0.0000751
```

Based on the following test data:

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~EE_variant, ~lambda, ~variable, ~value,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "blood_vessel_h16",                0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "adrenal_gland_h16",                0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "bone_element_h16",                0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "Bronchus_h16",                     0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "esophagus_h16",                    0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "extraembryonic_structure_h16",     0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "eye_h16",                          0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "gonad_h16",                        0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "heart_h16",                        0,
  "EE87786ln1", 0.0000228, "kidney_h16",                       0)
df2 <- tribble(
  ~EE_variant, ~lambda, ~variable, ~value,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "blood_vessel_h16",                0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "adrenal_gland_h16",                0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "bone_element_h16",                0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "Bronchus_h16",                     0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "esophagus_h16",                    0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "extraembryonic_structure_h16",     0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "eye_h16",                          0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "gonad_h16",                        0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "heart_h16",                        0,
  "EE87787ln1", 0.0000751, "kidney_h16",                       0)

dfList <- list(EE87786ln1 = df1, EE87787ln1 = df2)
```